# When Generating URL Characters Being Arbitrarily Moved

Tags: php, html, email, url, php-7.1

Received this from a customer, our password reset emails normally generate correctly, however what (in code) looks like this:

```
 <h4> <a href="https://'.$this->server.'/password?email_token='.$email_token.'&user_email='.$user_email.'">reset here</a></h4>
```

And the string that was generated was as followed:

```
https://password/?email_token=111111111111111111111aaaaaaabbbb&user_email=info@mail.com
```

Finally, this is what it should look like:

```
    https://website.com/password?email_token=111111111111111111111aaaaaaabbbb&user_email=info@mail.com
```

This is the interesting segment:

```
.'/password?
```

It was generated as followed:

```
password/?
```

Somehow when generating the email, the '/' before 'password' was moved after password, but before the '?'

It's a static string fragment, how could this happen?

Comment: interesting, by the way I wouldnt send user email for reseting password, I would create two tokens a long and a short one and save short one in db, then validate user with that token and let to reset password. and reset that token after reset success

Comment: did you try with different browsers? what was the result? Here works well => [Test example](https://3v4l.org/Y05bm)

Comment: @dilekkoç I do, the short one is saved to decode the long one and to compare it to the 'real' token store in the db, it's also time limited. Also, e-israel, the link is generated server side, so it's browser agnostic($this->server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; that trickles down through the system). I feel like $_SERVER failed to register a server name, but even then, it doesn't explain the '/'.

Comment: Taking a step back on my last comment, I don't have usecanonicalnames enabled (using virtual hosts), and per:https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php the value is being pulled by the client, so it might not have sent a value. That being said, it doesn't explain why the '/' was moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by the URL parsing within the client (Chrome, FireFox, Edge, and possibly other client interpreters like outlook). I did not test Opera but it does not occur in Internet Explorer 11.

For more details see: https://webkit.org/blog/7086/url-parsing-in-webkit/

The URL parsing may also be applied by the sending or receiving MTA such as; postfix, gmail, office.com, etc. However my testing with postfix and gmail did not alter the source code of the email message.
*We would need to know your server configuration and the recipient's MTA to validate.*

The actual string output in the PHP source code and resulting HTML is as expected

```
https:///password?email_token=111111111111111111111aaaaaaabbbb&user_email=info@mail.com
```

Since it is not a valid URI, as the domain provided by `$this->server` is missing, the offending client parses the URL and moves the extra `/`.

Run the snippet below to experience the URL parsing during click and mouseover in your browser: *Shortened the URL parameters for brevity.*

```html
<a href="https:///password?email_token=1">Test</a>
```

### Rendered Result:

[image: Rendered URL]

---

The same behavior can be experienced in Javascript when using `new URL()`.

```js
var url = 'https:///password?e=1';
var u = new URL(url);
window.alert('Original: ' + url + "\nParsed: " + u.href);
```

---

However when the domain is provided, the URL is not altered.

```html
<a href="https://example.com/password?email_token=1">Test</a>
```

Comment: it would make sense if it generated that url, but it generated: //password/? notice the '/' placed in a different position.

Comment: @Chris Correct, your PHP generates a URL of `https:///password?` because `$this->server` is empty. The browser interprets it as an invalid URI and alters the invalid `https:///` to `https://`.and appends it to `password/?`. Resulting in `https://password/?`. Simply put the domain is missing in your URL, because `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is not a reliable means to obtain the hostname. The URL is not altered in the source code, only in the browser rendering of it as demonstrated. The same URL parsing could also be applied by an MTA interpreter, like gmail.com, or office.com.

Comment: @Chris added an image of the rendered example for clarity, with the source code of the URL visible.

Comment: it would have to be re-formed before it hits the client as I tried viewing the source, but it showed the post re-formed url, but yours is the only logical answer.Thanks.

Comment: To be sure, generate the html with the headers, then use `file_put_contents('/tmp/email.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);` and send the message `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`. View the log to validate what you are actually sending. Are you using any specific library, like Swiftmailer. to send the emails, that may be parsing the message?